# Find the solution to this 4-by-4 matrix ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution to the system $y'=Ay$, where A is given by:

$A=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$

I have found the eigenvalues to be $\lambda_{1,2}=0, \lambda_{3,4}=-1$. Note that I am personally only interested in the contribution I will get from the zero eigenvalues, because I know the ones for -1 will give me solutions that tend to zero. So this is actually a part of a different problem I have to solve.

I found the eigenvector for $\lambda_{1,2}=0$ to be $\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ b\\ 0\\
0\\\end{pmatrix}$ (can someone double check that I've done this right?).

But here I've only gone to the null space of $(\lambda I - A)$, and I'm not sure whether I can argue that the contribution from the zero eigenvalues will be of the form:

$\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 0\\ 0\\
0\\\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ b\\ 0\\
0\\\end{pmatrix}$

Or do I need to proceed in a different way that would result in, say, finding a solution of the form $t \bf{v}$ for some eigenvector **v**?

Comment: Yes, you are are on the right track and can choose on eigenvector as (1,0,0,0) and the other as (0,1,0,0) for $\lambda_{1,2} = 0$ Now, you can move on to the other eigenvalue (-1) which will need a generalized eigenvector.

Comment: @Amzoti, so you'd agree that the general solution will have the form $y(t)=c_{1}(1,0,0,0)+c_{2}(0,1,0,0)+c_{3}e^{-t}\bf{v_{3}}$ $+ c_{4} t e^{-t} \bf{v_{4}}$, where $c_{1}, c_{2}, c_{3}, c_{4}$ are constants, and $\bf{v_{3}}$ and $\bf{v_{4}}$ are the eigenvectors for -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a solution that looks like a linear combination of the following:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & e^{-t} & 3 e^{-t} t\\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-t}
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured, but got so confused I couldn't think straight :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked out - remember patience, practice and persistence! You are doing great! Regards

Comment: +1 for my kind friend. I have seen that you have been trying to help others, so don't worry about some poor minus here. Do the job as you have done it. I like your answers. ;-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you: i truly believe the best benefit that we can provide is to help guide users to a better problem solving approach that focuses on clear arguments, thoughtful approaches and enough detail to move forward. I don't always give complete answers as users need to do some work - and I really struggle with where to draw the line. Having said that, I love helping people grow and learn! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: I have seen that though your works, step by step. I love this kind of teaching and I really do this way to my students as well. God bless the one who does his job as it should be.  Best Regards Amzoti.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head! Nice feedback, too.